# In bootstrap, Is class="col-sm-4" will be considered as class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4", if col-md and col-lg are not specied?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

If col-lg and col-md is not specifed in the class, then will col-sm be applied for all the large screens?

Comment: Yes. If you want to have the same width throughout the screens, you can simply add col-4 (bootstrap 4) which will take col-sm-4, col-md-4 and col-lg-4 automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

From [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid-intro),

> Grid classes apply to devices with screen widths greater than or equal to the breakpoint sizes, and override grid classes targeted at smaller devices. Therefore, e.g. applying any .col-md-* class to an element will not only affect its styling on medium devices but also on large devices if a .col-lg-* class is not present.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, In bootstrap if you use only class="col-sm-4" it will automatically adjust the property of "col-sm-4" for all screens.